# CSS / jQuery prevent Scrolling on certain Div

Tags: jquery, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="parentDisable"></div>
<div id="popup">
    <div class="karmalayer">
        <img src="<?php echo(IMG) ?>alpha-shadow.png">
        Thank you for visiting
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following attributes:

```
.karmawrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
    width: 100%;
}

.karmalayer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #337ab7;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.hlcolor {
    color: #337ab7;
}

.karmalayer img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.parentDisable{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index:10000;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#popup{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10001;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is to "disable" my background on opening the page and displaying a popup. Since my site is already loading in the background (and the site is pretty long), I want to disable the scroll-functionality. Basically, as long as the user is in the div `popup`, scrolling should not be allowed.

I tried to solve it with jQuery, but that didn't do the trick:

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
    init_scroll(event, delta);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For content to not be scrollable, wrap it in a container and set the overflow of that to hidden. The container needs a fixed height, so setting the position to absolute and height/width to 100% should fill the screen how you would normally expect the page content to. This will prevent scrollbars from appearing and prevent default scrollwheel action. Check for when the page has loaded before showing the content.

Also, if your page has so much content, perhaps breaking it into multiple pages would suffice? Or, loading content by ajax only when the user scrolls to it.